# What prevents website X from reading website Y's cookies?

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies

I have recently been reading about session ID's and how websites track users.
I was wondering how session ID's are safe inside cookies.  Couldn't a website read another website's cookies and get your session ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are stored on the client's browser with cookie name, value and the expiry. But multiple websites may have cookie with same name so cookies are grouped with respect to domains. See the Firefox's cookies screenshot bellow.

[image]

Suppose sites A and B have cookies with name ABC. Browser will provide the cookie data for site A from site A only.

Comment: Is it possible for site B to trick the browser into giving it cookies from A?

Comment: @user3853544 Yes. I have heard that we can get cookies of Y from X by adding iframe in X that loads Y... By the way it is called as cross domain cookies.